# How display italic fonts like an article document in beamer?

Tags: beamer, italic

I wish to display italics like this
[image: number 2 in italics] 
that are used in article documents, but within a beamer document with the `default` use and font themes.

Comment: Just for a particular individual character or are you trying to change all fonts to italics?

Comment: Actually it was meant for a particular part of the frame, but a global option seems interesting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your real needs, but this seems to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\italnum}[1]{\begingroup\fontfamily{cmr}\itshape#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is \italnum{1}}

A number $2$ and also italic \italnum{2}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it working also in math mode, let me know.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I was looking for, since it also works for the `\titlepage` components. Thanks a lot!